# reading grep patterns from files

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have a text file containing my input of strings to be grepped from other file along with content following the string. I am using

```
grep -A -f file1.txt file2.txt > output.txt
```

But it is not giving the result. Where I am doing mistake.

input file1

```
536911
536912
536920
```

input file 2

```
>gi|536911|CP006573.1|:c959-690 Mannheimia haemolytica D171, complete genome
ATGAAATGCGAACGTTTAGAAGAGTTATTAGAGTTACTTGGCGAACATTGGCGTAAAAATCCTGACTTAC
ACCTCATTGATATTTTGCAGCAGCTTTCAGTTGAAGTGGGCGAGCCTGATAATTTCAAAGCGTTAAGCGA
TGAAGTGTTAATCTATCAGCTTAAAATGCGAAATGCAGGCAAATTTGAGCCTATTCCCGGCATAAAAAAA
GATTATGAAGATGATTTTAAAACGGCTTTATTGCGAGCTCGTGGAATTTTAAACGATTAA
>gi|536912|gb|CP006573.1|:c6390-2194 Mannheimia haemolytica D171, complete genome
ATGAAGACCAAAACATTTACTCGTTCTTATCTTGCTTCTTTTGTAACAATCGTATTAAGTTTACCTGCTG
TAGCATCTGTTGTACGTAATGATGTGGACTATCAATACTTCCGCGATTTTGCCGAAAATAAAGGACCATT
TTCAGTTGGTTCAATGAATATTGATATTAAAGACAACAATGGACAACTTGTAGGCACGATGCTTCATAAT
TTACCAATGGTTGATTTTAGTGCTATGGTAAGAGGTGGATATTCTACTTTAATTGCACCACAATATTTAG
TTAGTGTTGCACATAATACTGGATATAAAAATGTTCAATTTGGTGCTGCAGGTTATAACCCTGATTCACA
TCACTATACTTATAAAATTGTTGACCGCAATGATTATGAAAAGGTTCAAGGAGGGTTGCACCCAGACTAT
>gi|536913|gb|CP006573.1|:7500-8540 Mannheimia haemolytica D171, complete genome
ATGTTTTATTCTAACAACCCTCTCATTAAACACAAGACCGGTTTATTAAATTTAGCAGAAGAACTGGGTA
ATATTTCTCAAGCCTGCAAAGTAATGGGAATGAGCCGAGATACATTCTATCGTTATCAACAAGCGGTTGA
GCAAGGTGGTGTTGAAGCATTGCTGAATCAAAATAGACGCGTTCCCAACTTAAAAAATCGTGTTGATGAG
```

required output

```
>gi|536911|CP006573.1|:c959-690 Mannheimia haemolytica D171, complete genome
ATGAAATGCGAACGTTTAGAAGAGTTATTAGAGTTACTTGGCGAACATTGGCGTAAAAATCCTGACTTAC
ACCTCATTGATATTTTGCAGCAGCTTTCAGTTGAAGTGGGCGAGCCTGATAATTTCAAAGCGTTAAGCGA
TGAAGTGTTAATCTATCAGCTTAAAATGCGAAATGCAGGCAAATTTGAGCCTATTCCCGGCATAAAAAAA
GATTATGAAGATGATTTTAAAACGGCTTTATTGCGAGCTCGTGGAATTTTAAACGATTAA
>gi|536912|gb|CP006573.1|:c6390-2194 Mannheimia haemolytica D171, complete genome
ATGAAGACCAAAACATTTACTCGTTCTTATCTTGCTTCTTTTGTAACAATCGTATTAAGTTTACCTGCTG
TAGCATCTGTTGTACGTAATGATGTGGACTATCAATACTTCCGCGATTTTGCCGAAAATAAAGGACCATT
TTCAGTTGGTTCAATGAATATTGATATTAAAGACAACAATGGACAACTTGTAGGCACGATGCTTCATAAT
TTACCAATGGTTGATTTTAGTGCTATGGTAAGAGGTGGATATTCTACTTTAATTGCACCACAATATTTAG
TTAGTGTTGCACATAATACTGGATATAAAAATGTTCAATTTGGTGCTGCAGGTTATAACCCTGATTCACA
TCACTATACTTATAAAATTGTTGACCGCAATGATTATGAAAAGGTTCAAGGAGGGTTGCACCCAGACTAT
```

How to achieve this task? Using grep or Sed

Thanks in advance

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: You are using `-A` without its required argument. See [man grep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep).

Comment: I am not getting anything..Argument failed..

Comment: Understood since I do no know the number of lines print after string, I missed that, any other way to get answer?

Comment: Looks like your input is a FASTA file. Have you looked at FASTA-related tools, and/or [tag:fasta] questions on StackOverflow?

Comment: Yes my input file is fasta but since my task related to extracting data using commands, I have not check fasta questions, now I'll check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are unsure of the number of lines following the pattern `-A` option wont help you.

An awk solution would be like

```
$ awk -F\| 'NR==FNR{pattern[$0];next} { if ($2 in pattern){flag=1} else if(NF > 1){flag=0}} flag' file1 file2
>gi|536911|CP006573.1|:c959-690 Mannheimia haemolytica D171, complete genome
ATGAAATGCGAACGTTTAGAAGAGTTATTAGAGTTACTTGGCGAACATTGGCGTAAAAATCCTGACTTAC
ACCTCATTGATATTTTGCAGCAGCTTTCAGTTGAAGTGGGCGAGCCTGATAATTTCAAAGCGTTAAGCGA
TGAAGTGTTAATCTATCAGCTTAAAATGCGAAATGCAGGCAAATTTGAGCCTATTCCCGGCATAAAAAAA
GATTATGAAGATGATTTTAAAACGGCTTTATTGCGAGCTCGTGGAATTTTAAACGATTAA
>gi|536912|gb|CP006573.1|:c6390-2194 Mannheimia haemolytica D171, complete genome
ATGAAGACCAAAACATTTACTCGTTCTTATCTTGCTTCTTTTGTAACAATCGTATTAAGTTTACCTGCTG
TAGCATCTGTTGTACGTAATGATGTGGACTATCAATACTTCCGCGATTTTGCCGAAAATAAAGGACCATT
TTCAGTTGGTTCAATGAATATTGATATTAAAGACAACAATGGACAACTTGTAGGCACGATGCTTCATAAT
TTACCAATGGTTGATTTTAGTGCTATGGTAAGAGGTGGATATTCTACTTTAATTGCACCACAATATTTAG
TTAGTGTTGCACATAATACTGGATATAAAAATGTTCAATTTGGTGCTGCAGGTTATAACCCTGATTCACA
TCACTATACTTATAAAATTGTTGACCGCAATGATTATGAAAAGGTTCAAGGAGGGTTGCACCCAGACTAT
```

**What it does?**

- `-F\|` sets the field seperator as `|`
- `'NR==FNR{pattern[$0];next}` stores the pattern from first file to an array `pattern`. Here `NR==FNR` true for the first file, `file1`
- `{ if ($2 in pattern){flag=1}` if the second column, `$2` is in array `pattern`, sets the `flag` as one
- `else if(NF > 1){flag=0}}` sets the `flag` as `0` only when the pattern is not found in the line and the line contian `>gi|xxxxx|`
- `flag` if the `flag` is set, performs the default action to print the entire line

Comment: nice ... but if `awk` is allowed `perl` should be too! :-)

Comment: Will the command depend on awk version and type of shell we are using?

Comment: It can. Which os are you using. try wit gnu awk

Answer (score 0):

you could remove the line ends and then make each record into a line:

```
cat file2.txt| tr -d '\n' | sed -e $'s/>gi/\\\n>gi/g'| grep -f file1.txt
```

Or paying heed to ["useless use of `cat`"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) **;-**)

```
tr -d '\n' < file2.txt | sed -e $'s/>gi/\\\n>gi/g' | grep -f file1.txt
```

à la `chomp`, `split` in Perl.

Comment: This script is working well but problem is in output file 'i' replaced by g n >gi replaced by >g. I am not worrying about this since, there is no change in desired sequence format. Thank you

Comment: sorry mixed up my cut and paste with my shell history :-(  - use `tr` **but only for line ends** then use `sed`. The point was to show that it's easier to do a simple replacement step with `tr` before using `sed` (and that `sed` needs double escaping to work from the shell)

Comment: hope this didn't cause any inconvenience

Comment: Finally I have done with analysis and I got required output..Thank you very much